# MongoDB overwrite validation error messages

Tags: mongodb, go, go-gin

I am using mongodb and mongo-driver to manage models and its data. I should translate the default validation messages to my native language.

That being said, I have being reading the [mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.0/mongo#hdr-Error_Handling) documentation but I couldn't find anything related on replacing the model validation errors.

Thus, I have my model `user.go` where:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email        string             `bson:"email" json:"email" binding:"required,email" validate:"is-unique"`
}
```

Then, whenever I send data where `email` is empty I get the default error message: `"Key: 'User.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'required' tag"`.

Suggestions?

Comment: You can try MongoDB [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/).

Comment: That specific errors comes from https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/d07eb88fb04047e450e834dd461210095fc28d6a/errors.go#L13 Have you looked at the "translations and custom errors" for that project?